# 2 input types for 1 html form field

Tags: php, html, forms, email, attributes

I need to add 2 input types for 1 form field in my html form viz. `type=email` and `type=number` for the html form field Email/mobile. How do I get this done? Below is the code:

```
 <label for="modlgn-username">Email/mobile</label>
 <input type="email" name="email" class="inputbox"  size="18" required />
```

Is it possible to add input `type=number` as well in the above code for the same field namely [Email/mobile]?

I'm a beginner and will apprecaite help in the matter a lot

Comment: No it is not possible. ANd nobody needs 2 input types for 1 field. And how can an email be numbers?

Comment: Why can't you use two fields?

Comment: actually what you are trying to ask?

Comment: you want a input box which allows you to write numbers and alphabets is it right

Comment: if you want what i have asked you then the below answer will be correct

Comment: I'll just ask you all to check facebook's login..that should solve all your doubts..facebook gives the option of logging in with number or email...How did facebook do that?

Answer (score 1):

[All HTML inputs Types](https://zedxtra.com.ng/html-input-tag/)

```
<input type="button">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="color">
<input type="date">
<input type="datetime-local">
<input type="email">
<input type="file">
<input type="hidden">
<input type="image">
<input type="month">
<input type="number">
<input type="password">
<input type="radio">
<input type="range">
<input type="reset">
<input type="search">
<input type="submit">
<input type="tel">
<input type="text">
<input type="time">
<input type="url">
<input type="week">
```

[Check Zedxtra.com.ng for how to use HTML tags](https://zedxtra.com.ng/html-input-tag/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible but you can take input type="text" for email/number.

Comment: Looking at this post, and many of your other posts, I've noticed an unsettling trend: Low Quality. Provide explanations, go into detail. Reference documentation, guide/give them direction. If you want to gain reputation, and be a meaningful contributor, these "one liners" are not going to work.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, are you asking if you can assign two input types to the same field?

I have never come across this and pretty sure it isn't possible. The best you can do to capture an email address or a phone number in the same field would be to make the field input type text. However, this would mean that your validation would get a bit harder.

Also, a side note. To ensure your form fields are accessible to users using assistive and adaptive technology (see https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/forms/) you want to make sure that your label "for" and your input "id" values match exactly. In the example below "firstname" is used to do this.

```
<label for="firstname">First name:</label>
<input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname">
```

This will help the screen reader associate the label with the form field.

Cheers,
Choppie

Comment: thanks...Jeez..urs was the best answer...u understood what i meant..Thanks really..Godbless

Comment: No worries. Noticed the FB site still use input type email for the box even though it can be used for an email address or a phone number. Not sure how their validation works though to allow for phone numbers.

Comment: Yes i checked too...they use type= email...i now have to crack my head on validation