# HTML input for a numeric pin

Tags: html

I am trying to write a basic program that takes a username and a numerical pin. I was hoping that it would be possible to have the input type "number" and "password" for the same input so that the input would show asterisks/dots instead of the number, but it didn't work. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance!

This is what I tried:

```
<label for="pin">PIN:</label><br>
<input type="number" type="password" id="pin"><br><br>
```

From [this Stack Overflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38827300/2-input-types-for-1-html-form-field) I found that it is not possible to add two input types.

Comment: I think this is duplicated like said in the comment by @0stone0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can obscure the PIN input with the `text-security` CSS property, applied to the numeric input field. In the head of your HTML document, include this:

```
<style>
  input {
    text-security:disc;
    -webkit-text-security:disc;
    -moz-text-security:disc;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use two types for the same input, instead you should use password type input, and just allow introducing numbers.

You can use something like this:

```html
<input type="password" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric">
```

This is just a Regular expression allowing numbers.